# Arrange multiple classes in javascript code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there a way to put multiple classes in one code?

I have many of those ".dwlnd-trg" classes. Like ".dwlnd-trg2", ".dwlnd-trg3" ".dwlnd-trg4" and ".dwlnd", ".dwlnd2", ".dwlnd3", ".dwlnd4" and so on.

Only ".s-dwlnd" stays always the same because this is the class which displays an animated svg image.

At the moment i have copied and pasted a working code in my website's head and it's great but would it be much cleaner if it's not 4, 6 or soon 8 instead of one good looking code? :) I tried to but without success...

here's the code looking so far:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".dwlnd-trg" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".dwlnd").removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
});});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".dwlnd-trg2" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd2" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".dwlnd2").removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
});});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".dwlnd-trg3" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd3" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".dwlnd3").removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
});});

$( document ).ready(function() {
$( ".dwlnd-trg4" ).click(function() {
    $( ".dwlnd4" ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $(".dwlnd4").removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
});});
```

Comment: What's your HtML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can do it based on id it makes it a lot easier because you can't have multiple id's. But you can have multiple classes. Here is an example with id.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dwlnd-trg, #dwlnd-trg2, #dwlnd-trg3, #dwlnd-trg11, #dwlnd-trghahaha").click(function() {
    //get the id of the trigger element that is clicked
    var thisId = $(this).attr("id");
    //get everything after "dwlnd-trg" form the id.
    var idStripped = thisId.replace('dwlnd-trg','');
    
    //Use the found id addition in the selector
    $(".dwlnd" + idStripped).addClass("s-dwlnd");

    setTimeout(function() {
      $(".dwlnd" + idStripped).removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
  });
});
```

```css
.s-dwlnd {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="dwlnd-trg">dwlnd-trg</button>
<button id="dwlnd-trg2">dwlnd-trg2</button>
<button id="dwlnd-trg3">dwlnd-trg3</button>
<button id="dwlnd-trg11">dwlnd-trg11</button>
<button id="dwlnd-trghahaha">dwlnd-trghahaha</button>

<div class="dwlnd">dwlnd</div>
<div class="dwlnd2">dwlnd2</div>
<div class="dwlnd3">dwlnd3</div>
<div class="dwlnd11">dwlnd11</div>
<div class="dwlndhahaha">dwlndhahaha</div>
```

Comment: Yeah, this worked very fine, thx! As you change the code is it now possible to go higher than number 9?

Comment: @user10688226 Yes, as you can see in the example it doesnt even need to be a number. All characters after `dwlnd-trg` in the id will be added to the class selector ".dwlnd". Se the id `dwlnd-trghahaha` results in the class selector `.dwlndhahaha`

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, this is a cleaner solution.

Besides the fact that your function becomes concise, easy to understand and maintain and you don't have to update it to add new items, on the markup side it separates the meaning of class (as a style anchor) from what it's working as a selector for the function.

I can't know your context but, If you also don't need different classes for the target div, you can also use attributes to set the right target.

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
  
  
  $(".dwlnd-trg").click(function() {
    // save the target reference via ref attribute
    var intref = $( this ).attr( 'ref' );
    
    // pass the target reference to get the right one
    $( ".dwlnd"+intref ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".dwlnd"+intref ).removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
    
    
  });
  
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <style>
    .s-dwlnd { border: solid 1px #ccc; color:red;}
  </style> 
  <!--use ref attribute as a target reference -->
  <div class="dwlnd-trg" ref="1">click me! (1)</div>
  <div class="dwlnd-trg" ref="2">click me! (2)</div>
  <div class="dwlnd1">animate me! 1</div>
  <div class="dwlnd2">animate me! 2</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Great alternative, but instead of `ref` I would use the `data()` function of jQuery for that instead of a `ref` attribute. https://api.jquery.com/data/

Comment: @MarkBaijens Yep, `data()` could open other options implementation here, depends on the case and how you want to tackle it.

Answer (score 1):

To put multiple class, you to try something like :

```
  $( ".dwlnd-trg, .dwlnd-trg2, .dwlnd-trg2" )
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector like this:

```
$('[class^="dwlnd-trg"]') //Select every element that has a class attribute starting with "dwlnd-trg".
```

or

```
$('[class˜="dwlnd-trg"]') //Select every element that has a class attribute containing "dwlnd-trg".
```

But beware the performance issue (since selecting from class is a much faster approach)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [attribute starts with selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/):

```
$( '[class^="dwlnd-trg"]' ).click(function() {
    var n = this.className.match(/\d+$/)[0] // grab the number
    $( ".dwlnd" + n ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );
    setTimeout(function() {
        $( ".dwlnd" + n ).removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you only need one $(document).ready. Just place all code in one block.

Second, you can create a function that takes the class of the selector as parameter.

Example:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
// Put all handlers here

   $( ".dwlnd-trg4" ).click(function() {
      addclass(dwlnd4);
    });
   $( ".dwlnd-trg3" ).click(function() {
      addclass(dwlnd3);
    });    
});

function addClass(class){
    ("." + class ).addClass( "s-dwlnd" );

    setTimeout(function() {
        $("." + class).removeClass("s-dwlnd");
    }, 3000); // Delay of 3 seconds

}
```

But if you really want to best function, I would suggest adding a date-attribute to the html. And work with an e.target so you would know which element has been clicked. But maybe this refactor is too big for you. I could add an example of this if you are interested.

Comment: How would the code exactly look when I put everything in one block? I'm a totaly noob, sorry.

Comment: I editted my answer en there are know 2 click events in your the document ready block. Functions don't have to be in the document ready block actually because they only get called from the ready state. This is not the full example but I guess you can add the remaing click handlers now :)